# error C1083: Cannot open include file: '\inc\wxp\warning.h': No such file or directory

Tags: windows, build, visual-studio-2013, driver, wdm

Background:
So I picked up Programming the Windows Driver model and tried to build the very first sample it has using visual studio 2013 Ultimate. While the book seems very reputed, there is no update for the sample code.

I saw some signs to used the older "build" instead of current msbuild / visual studio. But that is another learning I am not prepared to do unless required (especially as I didnt find nmake or build quickly enough and i ll be learning older build processes which I dont need to use).

Problem:
error C1083: Cannot open include file: '\inc\wxp\warning.h': No such file or directory stddcls.cpp

Building the sample gives me this error.
I included the folders for wdm.h and warning.h in the includes path. Wdm.h got resolved, but warning.h continues to throw an error - and I dont even know where warning.h in included/referenced.

I can post the entire code if required.

Yes, I am new to driver development.

If this book is too old to use, pointers to "newer" tutorials of Windows driver dev is appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you need to learn WDM I didn't like the Oney book, I preferred the [Windows NT Device Driver Development book](https://www.osronline.com/custom.cfm?name=index_fullframeset.cfm&pageURL=https://www.osronline.com/store/index.cfm) instead. It's an easier and more organized read IMO. Depending on what you are trying to do you should also look in to WDF, and if you can avoid kernel mode for your driver look specifically in to UMDF.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual studio
Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Forced Include file.

There is a hardlink to warning.h here. This needs to be changed to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\warning.h and the error goes away!

Answer (score 0):

Another useful link for "Programming the Windows Driver Model" Oney:

http://csserver.evansville.edu/~reising/EE%20356%20Fall%202005/Changes%20to%20files%20from%20Walter%20Oney.pdf