# Setting the $(KIT_SHARED_IncludePath) variable for driver header inclusions

Tags: c#, windows, build, driver, wdk

Following https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439654(v=vs.85).aspx

I received an error similar to this one: [error C1083: Cannot open include file: '\inc\wxp\warning.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135062/error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-inc-wxp-warning-h-no-such-file-or-dir/24146179#24146179)

The suggested fix does remedy the initial problem, however, there are other unlocated header files. Rather than locate and change each path manually, how would I set $(KIT_SHARED_IncludePath) to point to the correct folder, since the error appears to be arising due to this path variable being incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting KIT_SHARED_IncludePath yourself: the value is automatically set by the WDK toolset to the location where shared headers are located.

I don't know why you are including "inc\wxp\warning.h", but I'm pretty sure that recent WDKs (any WDK since Windows 8) don't ship headers in such locations (there is no "inc\wxp" directory).

You should be able to simply #include warning.h (without any directories) and that should do the trick, since $(KIT_SHARED_IncludePat) is part of the default include path for all drivers.

Comment: Okay thank you. This is on windows 10 with visual studio 2015, trying to compile the basic KMDF driver which I did not write. I think the problem is the value of Kit_Shared_IncludePath is currently not correct for the current versions. I did not encounter this error with the stable 8.1 builds.

Comment: In the Win10 WDK, by default, it should be pointing to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\<KitVersion>\shared", where <KitVersion> is something like 10.0.xxxxx.0.

When building, you can figure out the value being used by increasing the built output verbosity (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx for instructions). The disagnostic level should show you the value being used for all MSBuild properties.

Comment: Thank you, using the previously linked question here, I was able to figure out the file path, and actually hardcode it in the mentioned 'Forced Include Variable' under Advanced in properties, and this resulted in no longer receiving the warning.h not found. However, I received an error that it could not find a different specific header file which was also located in the same directory. Therefore, I thought that it might be easier to change the variable rather than ferret out every instance where the variable is used and needs to be changed. Thanks again for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that Visual Studio 2015 is not correctly configured.

Have you read http://www.windrvr.com/2015/05/11/wdk-installation-tips/ ?
You should be able to change the installation from the control panel and add the "Tools and Windows SDK 10.0.xxxxx" which seems to be required.

Comment: I believe both the SDK and WDK were installed and configured properly and the issue was with the new file path not being included at that time in windows 10.
Currently, you also experience a similar problem using python --compiler msvc, as it has the paths for earlier visual studios.
  I believe the correct solution to this problem is to add a system environment variable along the lines of: VS90COMNTOOLS = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools so that when looking for the build tools it finds the correct version

I will reconfigure and check again, thank you!